# TestHarness helper function fails for MatButtonHarness

Tags: typescript, angular-material, karma-mocha

Given this helper function:

```
async function findHarnessByTestID(
    typeQualifier: (options?: InputHarnessFilters | undefined) => HarnessPredicate<any>, 
    testId: string) {
       return loader.getHarness(typeQualifier({ selector: `[data-test-id=${testId}]` }));
}
```

This test works just fine:

```
it('shows the icon', async () => {
   const icon = (await findHarnessByTestID(MatIconHarness.with, 'icon-test-id')) as MatIconHarness;
   expect(await icon.getName()).to.equal('alarm');
});
```

But this test does not:

```
it('shows the row menu items', async () => {
  const menuButtonHarness = (await findHarnessByTestID(MatButtonHarness.with, 'button-test-id')) as MatButtonHarness;
  expect(true).to.be.true;
}
```

I recognize the helper function isn't particularly useful, but I would like to understand what's breaking here. Can anyone see why this breaks for MatButtonHarness but not for MatIconHarness?

Error output:

> ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hostSelector')', '; Zone:', 'ProxyZone', '; Task:', 'mocha.forceTask', '; Value:', TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hostSelector')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hostSelector')
> at HarnessPredicate.getSelector (http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2022/testing.mjs:337:38)
> at map (http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2022/testing.mjs:512:123)
> at Array.map ()
> at http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2022/testing.mjs:512:96
> at Generator.next ()
> at asyncGeneratorStep (http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
> at _next (http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
> at executor (http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:27:1)
> at ZoneAwarePromise (http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:1411:21)
> at http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:19:1, 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hostSelector')
> at HarnessPredicate.getSelector (http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2022/testing.mjs:337:38)
> at map (http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2022/testing.mjs:512:123)
> at Array.map ()
> at http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2022/testing.mjs:512:96
> at Generator.next ()
> at asyncGeneratorStep (http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
> at _next (http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
> at executor (http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:27:1)
> at ZoneAwarePromise (http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:1411:21)
> at http://localhost:4201/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:19:1'